# My question is on the unit vector in the direction of a given vector

Tags: vectors

My question is about the unit vector in the direction of a given vector.

Given the following vectors $A = 2i + 3j + k$ and $B = 4i + 2j -k$, find $I_A \times I_B$, where $I_A$ is the unit vector in the direction of vector $A$  while $I_B$ is the unit vector in the direction of vector $B$.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Easier: Find $A\times B$ and *then* turn it into a unit vector.

Comment: @TedShifrin The cross product of unit vectors isn’t itself necessarily a unit vector, though.

Comment: Right, I misread. Apologies.

Comment: My correct comment should have been to compute $A\times B$ and then divide by the product of the magnitudes of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thanks Ted, i tried it and voila it worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector A= unit vector of A* magnitude of A
Similar is for vector B.
Then take the cross product of Ia X Ib where Ia is unit vector of A and Ib is unit vector of B.
You should be getting your answer in terms of  Ic

Answer (score 1):

To get the unit vector in the direction of $\vec v$, just multiply by the scalar $\frac1{\lvert \vec v\rvert}$, where ${\lvert \vec v\rvert}=\sqrt{v_1^2+v_2^2+v_3^2}$.

So, for instance,  $IA=\frac1{\sqrt{14}}\cdot(2i+3j+k)$.